# Can't install w3af

Tags: python, openssl

Well i am not able able to install w3af I tired
`sudo apt-get install w3af`

It says

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:`

`w3af : Depends: python-pyopenssl`

`E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

For which when I checked is said to be included in `python-openssl` package which is fairly updated and I also tried `sudo apt-get clean` to check for the broken dependencies but it returns nothing.

So I am not able to decide exactly what to be done !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution went pretty simple. Do `sudo apt-get install python2.6` and try to `reinstall w3af`.It will install easily.